# How can I unmarshal xml to interface array?

Tags: xml, go

I have many structures in my app. And i want to deserialize all them into []interface{}.

How can i do this? I only can write concrete type array for each structure.
Maybe any custom packages can this?

This:

```
<Root>
 <Button></Button>
 <Checkbox></Checkbox>
 <Someelse></Someelse>
</Root>
```

to this:

```
type Root struct {
   Content []interface{}
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-6hNKWdsIYn

Comment: Does the content of the root tag change in some way each time, if so, then surely a map would be a better choice. A struct is a fixed element that would hardcode this structure and is perhaps not the best choice for such a dynamic XML structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I unmarshal xml to [...] a []interface?

You cannot. Dead simple. Package encoding/xml does not support this.

Comment: Maybe any custom packages can this?

Comment: @GLeBaTi asking for 3rd party packages libraries etc. is OT on SO.